# Constructor-Based Dependency Injection within Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have this class:

```
@Service     
public class DogUserService  {               
private final ManagerService managerService;
...
}
```

and on my context.xml:

```
   <bean id="managerService"
        class="com.dogs.impl.services.ManagerService" />
```

but when I run the app. I have this error:

```
    rvice.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.dogs.impl.services.ManagerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency a
    nnotations: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the bean using @Bean annotation to the WebApplicationContext. I have created the managerService bean from context.xml within a @Configuration bean and made the  bean available in webApplicationContext with @Bean method. This UserService class which has managerService as autowired has the property @ConditionalOnBean for this configuration bean.

Below is how I have implemented it.

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication public class DemoApplication
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnBean({EnableConfiguration.class})
public class UserService
{
    @Autowired
    private ManagerService managerService;
    
    public String run() {
        System.out.println("Going to Run from manager Service");
        return managerService.run();
    }

}
```

**EnableConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class EnableConfiguration implements InitializingBean
{

    ManagerService managerService;

    @Bean
    public ManagerService mngrService() {
        return managerService;
    }

    @Override public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "context.xml" );
        managerService = (ManagerService) ctx.getBean("managerService");
        System.out.println("manager bean:" + managerService.toString());
        mngrService();

    }
}
```

**ManagerService**

```
public class ManagerService
{
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public ManagerService(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String run() {
        return this.toString();
    }

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return "ManagerService{" + "a=" + a + ", b=" + b + '}';
    }
}
```

**ServiceController**

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String test() {
        return userService.run();
    }
}
```

**context.xml**

```
    <bean id="managerService" class="com.example.demo.ManagerService">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="2"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="5"/>
    </bean>
```